# How to save the color of my favorite button in Hive db?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to create a favorite button for my app. Which work is to  change and save color, while the user press it, So I decided to use hive db for it. The problem is, when i tap on the button; the color get changed, but when i move to other page or hot start/reload the page, the color changed back to it former self automatically. As i am a beginner i cant understand what value i have to put in the hive db to save the button-color. To indicate the user its being marked as favorite.

```
    class p1 extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _p1State createState() => _p1State();
    }

    class _p1State extends State<p1> {
    bool _isFavorite = true;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
       body:Stack(
           children:<Widget>[
           Image(
           image:AssetImage("Image/Chowsun1.jpg"),
         fit:BoxFit.cover,
         width: double.infinity,
         height: double.infinity,
         ),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('   Its you '
                  ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "Explora",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900 ) )



             ),
             Stack ( children: [Positioned(
               top:90,
               right: 20,
               child:const Text('   1 ',
                 style: TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 25.0,
                     color: Colors.white,
                     fontFamily: "Comforter"
                   ),
                   ),
                   )], ),





        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: (
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                        color:_isFavorite ? Colors.white: Colors.red


                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        _isFavorite= !_isFavorite;
                      });

                      Hive.box(FAVORITES_BOX).put(_isFavorite, !_isFavorite);

                    }
                )
            )
        )])

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing you have to remember is that, you are initialising the `_isFavorite` to `true` and not getting it from the db. It means, you are just saving it to `hive` but not retrieving from it. I didn't use hive, but I understood the above from your code. It is expected that the icon is always white when you change/reload the screen. You need to retrieve the value of `isFavorite` in `initState()`

Comment: @immadisairaj Sir,can you please provide the example code?

Comment: You could override [`initState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) function in your `_p1State` class. In that function you need to use `_isFunction = Hive.box(..).get(..)`. Or you could use a `Listener` which is mentioned in [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive). Recommend you to going through the code from [this](https://github.com/hivedb/hive#hive-%EF%B8%8F-flutter) section.

Comment: You need to save the value Hiveobj.save(), and then you need to fetch it. Hope it helps

Comment: @TejaswiniDev sir can you please provide some example code?

Comment: Sure, I will update you